# MYSQL joining 2 tables accross multiple fields

Tags: mysql, left-join

It should be oh so simple, but perhaps the wine has gone to my head.

Table A (things that need parts)

```
id | Name          | part1 | part2 | part 3 | part 4 | etc
1  | This thing    | 1    | 2    |  3    |  2    | etc
2  | another thing | 1    | 1    |  4    |  5    | etc
3  | even more     | 11   | 2    |  2    |  2    | etc
```

Table B (parts)

```
id | Description  
1  | I am a part   
2  | I am another Part
3  | Im a very imprtant part
```

A;; i actually need to do is select all the "parts" that each "thing" needs by its "DESCRIPTION"

so I get a each line in English rather than ID no's

ie

```
id  | Thing name | part 1       | part 2       | part 3       | part 4 
1   | This Thing | name of part | name of part | name of part | name of part
```

Like i said, complete memory overload here and Ive lost the will to live. Any help very gratefull recieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think rather than doing left join, in long run it's better normalize your data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will look something like this. Its been a while since I wrote a MySQL query. I am sure somebody could improve on it.

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b1.description,
    b2.description,
    b3.description,
    b4.description
FROM
    table_a `a`
        LEFT JOIN
    table_b `b1`
        ON a.part1 = b1.id
        LEFT JOIN
    table_b `b2`
        ON a.part2 = b2.id
        LEFT JOIN
    table_b `b3`
        ON a.part3 = b3.id
        LEFT JOIN
    table_b `b4`
        ON a.part4 = b4.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data model has doomed you to complexity from the start.

```
select
*
from TableA A
left join TableB B1 on A.part1 = B1.id
left join TableB B2 on A.part2 = B1.id
left join TableB B3 on A.part3 = B1.id
left join TableB B4 on A.part4 = B1.id
```

This is untested, but if you "unpivot" TableA many more possibilities open up.
**e.g.**

```
SELECT
      A.id
    , A.Name
    , GROUP_CONCAT(B.Description ORDER BY A.rowno) as PartsList
FROM (
      SELECT
            A1.id
          , A1.Name
          , cj.rowno
          , CASE
                  WHEN cj.rowno = 1 THEN part1
                  WHEN cj.rowno = 2 THEN part2
                  WHEN cj.rowno = 3 THEN part3
                  WHEN cj.rowno = 4 THEN part4
            END AS LinkID
      FROM TableA a1
            CROSS JOIN ( 1 AS rowno
                  UNION ALL SELECT 2
                  UNION ALL SELECT 3
                  UNION ALL SELECT 4
                  ) cj
      ) A
      LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.LinkId = B.ID
GROUP BY
      A.id
    , A.Name
```

and, if TableA was normalized permanently you would not need these complexities.